# How to construct a two-qubit circuit implementing the oracle for Simon's algorithm, in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction

I want to create a two-qubit quantum circuit for a function with these inputs and outputs:

f(00)=10

f(01)=10

f(10)=01

f(11)=01

I do not know how to think about this problem systematically and come up with a quantum circuit.
Please note that I am using Qiskit so consider the Qiskit order.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MarcoFellous-Asiani. It is going to be an oracle for Simon's Algorithm. Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Simon's algorithm, the oracle maps $|0\rangle|x\rangle$ to $|f(x)\rangle|x\rangle$. In your case:
$$|00\rangle|00\rangle \rightarrow |10\rangle|00\rangle$$
$$|00\rangle|01\rangle \rightarrow |10\rangle|01\rangle$$
$$|00\rangle|10\rangle \rightarrow |01\rangle|10\rangle$$
$$|00\rangle|11\rangle \rightarrow |01\rangle|11\rangle$$

**Note:** Like Qiskit, I'm using little-endian bit ordering.

This is a unitary operation and can be easily implemented:

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(4)

circ.cx(1, 2)
circ.cx(2, 3)
circ.x(3)
```

[image]

And to test the output of this circuit, you can use this code snippet:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

sv = Statevector.from_label('00++').evolve(circ)
sv.draw('latex')
```

Comment: It is going to be an oracle for Simon's Algorithm. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Yes! I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be correct. How did you come up with such a circuit? I am trying to develop my intuition about quantum circuits.